# Finding the local name of an XNATPy object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xnat

I am trying out **XNATpy** and I am accessing files that are not installed locally on my computer. How can I get the name of the file object I am accessing, such as "1.3.6.1...-18s1eb2.dcm"?

My code:

```
file_obj = connection.projects['project'].subjects['S'].experiments['EXP'].scans['T1'].resources['DICOM'].files[0] 

print (file_obj)
```

My output when I print the object:

```
<FileData 1.3.6.1...-18s1eb2.dcm (1.3.6.1...-18s1eb2.dcm)>
```

I tried `file_obj.get_name()` and `file_obj.name()` but both give me an AttributeError, saying that '`FileData`' object has no attribute 'name' or '`get_name`'

```
print(dir(file_obj))

['SECONDARY_LOOKUP_FIELD', '_CONTAINED_IN', '_DISPLAY_IDENTIFIER', '_HAS_FIELDS', '_XSI_TYPE', '__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '__xsi_type__', '_abc_impl', '_cache', '_caching', '_fieldname', '_fields', '_overwrites', '_parent', '_path', '_uri', '_xnat_session', 'caching', 'cat_id', 'clearcache', 'collection', 'data', 'del_', 'delete', 'digest', 'download', 'download_stream', 'external_uri', 'fieldname', 'file_content', 'file_format', 'file_size', 'file_tags', 'full_data', 'fulldata', 'fulluri', 'get', 'get_object', 'id', 'logger', 'mset', 'open', 'parent', 'path', 'query', 'set', 'size', 'uri', 'xnat_session', 'xpath']
```

Comment: You can `print (dir(file_obj))` to see what attributes are there

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated the post!

Comment: The [documentation](https://xnat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/static/tutorial.html#getting-external-urls-of-an-object) mentions `external_uri`. Is this the name you are looking for?

Comment: `path` and `uri` also looks like good candidates. Note that it's not a Python file object in the [usual sense](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).